# How to convert date of the form 'xxth Mar XXXX' in 'DD/MM/YY' format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'am getting date output in the form of `xxth Mar XXXX` format and I need it in `DD/MM/YY`.

Take an example: 18th Mar 2021 is what I'am getting, expected output should be like `18/03/2021`

What is the best solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) you will find anything you want. 
Or you can use `moment` library like: `moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moments.js [Library](https://momentjs.com/) , then you can use moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")
to get the desire output.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `moment` library, but it doesn't work as expected.

```js
const moment = require('moment');

console.log(moment('12th Mar 2021').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

I got the following warning message, and the date fell back to `Date()`:

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
```

So I have switched to `dayjs`, and it works

```js
const customParseFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat');
// without customParseFormat, it won't work
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
dayjs.extend(customParseFormat);

console.log(dayjs('12th Mar 2021', 'DD[th] MMM YY').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Furthermore, `dayjs` is much more smaller than `moment`.